# Hide a div element on button click and replace it with another div without using jquery

Tags: javascript, css, html, web

This is my HTML code. on page load it displays two tab buttons and images under it. On a button click over any tab the images should disappear and the tab content should load. But it is not loading the required div content, simply removing the images.

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openC(event, 'admin')">Login as Admin</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openC(event, 'mac')">Login as MAC</button>

  <div id="images">

    <div id="admin">
      <img src="D:\Users\temp\Desktop\admin login.jpg" alt="Admin">
    </div>

    <div id="mac">
      <img src="D:\Users\temp\Desktop\mac.png" alt="MAC">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="admin" class="tabcontent">

    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="container">
          HELLO
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="mac" class="tabcontent">

    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="container">
         HII
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS function.

```js
function openC(evt, Name) {
  document.getElementById("images").style.display = "none";
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same id, you have the "admin" and "mac" ids in the div with the id "images". Change them to something else and the code should work.